# Android - Monkey throttling not working as specified

Tags: android, stress-testing

I'm using Monkey to stress test one of my company's Android applications. However, the `--throttle` switch does not seem to work as specified.

For example, I set Monkey to inject an input event every 500 milliseconds. While the Monkey runner id noticeably slow down, it would still sometimes send multiple events in rapid succession. I then set the throttling to 5,000 milliseconds, but the issue would persist.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you say "in rapid succession", do you mean more frequently than every 500 milliseconds? It might be helpful if you edited the question to add your full command line (I am not experienced with using Monkey, but those who are might be able to help with more information)

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue.

What I was using: 
./adb shell monkey -p your.company.name **-v 50 --throttle 1000**

Correct syntax: 
./adb shell monkey -p your.company.name **--throttle 1000 -v 50**

According to the syntax mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html), all options should be *before* the event-count.

If you are already using this correctly, the "multiple events in rapid succession" should be the key, trackball events.
For e.g.

> :Sending Trackball (ACTION_MOVE): 0:(-3.0,3.0) 
> :Sending Trackball (ACTION_MOVE): 0:(-5.0,-2.0) 
> :Sending Trackball (ACTION_MOVE): 0:(2.0,2.0) 
> :Sending Trackball (ACTION_MOVE): 0:(-1.0,1.0) 
> :Sending Trackball (ACTION_MOVE): 0:(0.0,-1.0)

and

> :Sending Key (ACTION_DOWN): 19    // KEYCODE_DPAD_UP 
> :Sending Key (ACTION_UP): 19    // KEYCODE_DPAD_UP

are grouped together (without the throttle delay), but are still counted towards the event count as 5 and 2 resp.